Where can I find the Talmud Bavli in Spanish online?
I have been using archive.org to read the Talmud in Spanish online but sadly now their website is down. Does anyone know where else I can find it? Any advice on where to find Jewish texts in Spanish online is also helpful.

What other texts would you like recommendations for?

Other texts include: Talmud Yerushalmi and Rashi's commentary in Spanish (in archive.org they had a PDF of "Torá con Rashi").

Here are the 5 books of Moses with Rashi in Hebrew and Spanish: https://es.chabad.org/dailystudy/torahreading.htm . I am not aware of any editions of the Yerushalmi in Spanish online (frankly I'm not even sure it exists in print)

Here is a site with dozens of Spanish-language judaica books as PDFs: https://www.zglibrosdejudaismo.com/

It's not available for free, but Tashema has a wonderful translation of the Babli as both a printed edition and an app.

thanks but do you know of a website that has them as PDF's not printed books?

I do not, @Yerushalma, but Tashema has them as an Android or iPhone application

Thank you @יהושע ק
I found the Talmud Bavli in Spanish on Scribd as a PDF.
